# Character Limit for Text Box for a telephone number

Tags: c#, textbox

I'm doing a project in which I take in a customers details (Title, Forename, Contact Number etc) and store them in a database. (The database and UI are in the same project!) I have a sign up form in which I've created a click event where it should sign a customer up to the system. For validation, I was wondering how I would go about setting the length for a telephone number. my telephone number data type is set as string in the UI(User Interface) and the user has to use a text box to enter their telephone number.

I would like the length to be set as 11 but can't seem to set it as this without the system throwing errors and exceptions. Here's what I've done so far:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmbxTitle.Text) || 
  txtForename.Text = "" || 
  txtSurname.Text = "" || 
  txtContactNo.Text = "" || 
  txtContactNo < //this is where I need help)
{
    MessageBox.Show("");
}
```

My `ContactNo` variable is the variable I wish to set to be exactly 11 characters. Any suggestions?

*Using c# and on Visual Studio 2022*

Comment: Is this winforms? Try a masked textbox, or read about ways to validate data [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/input-keyboard/validation?view=netdesktop-6.0)

Comment: How about [String.Length](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.length?view=net-7.0)?

Comment: A TextBox has a [TextLength](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.textlength?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) property that'll tell you how many characters are in it. Might want to call Trim() against the Text() property, though, to account for whitespace. A more robust solution would use a well formed Regular Expression to see if what the user typed in matches different patterns of a phone number.